Amazon SP-API Errors - "'item_name' is required but not supplied." and "'color' is required but not supplied."
I'm listing parent/child items all at once via Amazon SP-API call putListingsItem.
The requests are accepted by the API and submission IDs received.
I call getListingsItem to see for any issues and I'm always getting following errors for several items I've tried to list.
"'item_name' is required but not supplied."

"'color' is required but not supplied."

Strange thing is getListingsItem call returns the attributes as well, and I can see both item_name and color in the attributes.
I can also see item name in my Amazon inventory but it's greyed out.
The request JSON must be correct because it's accepted but the API. I have no trademarks or copyrighted info in the item_name.
Tried developer support and have been waiting for a helpful response for several days now. I'm hoping someone else has run into this problem before and can shed some light on it.
